# Change CSS of future instances

Tags: jquery, css

I display images, by default they are sorted by two in a row (50% width), I have an option with jQuery to display 4 in a row. It works as expected until you try to load more images (using infinite scroll).

The "next/future instances" will have 50% width again even though I changed the css by clicking a jQuery button. **How do I ensure future instances will have the updated css?**

```
$('.sortbutton4').click(function() 
{ 
    $('.imagecontainer').css({"width": "24.5%", "margin": "0.25%"}); 
    $('.sortbutton4').css({"display": "none"});
    $('.sortbutton2').css({"display": "block"});
});

$('.sortbutton2').click(function() 
{ 
    $('.imagecontainer').css('width', '48.5%');
    $('.imagecontainer:nth-child(odd)').css({"margin-left": "1%", "margin-right": "0.5%"});
    $('.imagecontainer:nth-child(even)').css({"margin-left": "0.5%", "margin-right": "1%"});
    $('.sortbutton2').css({"display": "none"}); 
    $('.sortbutton4').css({"display": "block"});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use CSS classes.
Something like:

```css
._4-in-a-row .imagecontainer {
  width: 24.5%;
  margin: 0.25%;
}
.imagecontainer {
  width: 48.5%;
}
```

and etc... for the `nth-child` selectors

Then just change the class of the element wrapping the image-containers.

```html
<div class='images'>
  <div class="imagecontainer">
    <!-- ..where your dynamically fetched/generated image appears.. -->
  </div>
  <div class="imagecontainer">
  </div>
  <div class="imagecontainer">
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
function toggleImageSize() {
   var imageRow = document.querySelector('.images');
  // toggle .4-in-a-row class
   imageRow.classList.contains('_4-in-a-row') ?
    imageRow.classList.remove('_4-in-a-row') : imageRow.classList.add('_4-in-a-row');
  // the rest of your JS for toggling the button visibility
}
```

Comment: A CSS classname cannot begin with a number.

Comment: @Rob Thanks, I forgot about that. Corrected

Answer (score 1):

The reason you see that behavior is that you are setting the existing elements' inline CSS upon clicking. When you add new items, they won't have the inline CSS applied. Instead you should use a parent class toggled to cascade the change down.

With that said, this can be done much more elegantly with flexbox.

HTML, note: using custom tag...b/c 2020

```
<button>4 columns</button>
<image-gallery>
  <img src="image.png" />  
  <img src="image.png" />  
  <img src="image.png" />  
  <img src="image.png" />  
  <img src="image.png" />  
  <img src="image.png" />  
  <img src="image.png" />  
  <img src="image.png" />  
  <img src="image.png" />   
</image-gallery>
```

CSS

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box; // this makes percent calculations include border and padding
}

image-gallery { // custom tag
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

image-gallery.four-columns img {
  width: 25%;
}

image-gallery img {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 1vw;
}
```

JQuery

```
$('button').click(function(){
  $('image-gallery').toggleClass('four-columns');

   buttonText = $(this).html() == "4 columns"
    ? "2 columns"
    : "4 columns";
  $(this).html(buttonText);
});
```

Comment: Note that `<img>` tags do not use and do not need a closing slash and never have in HTML.